# Visualize tagged images on Windows

Tags: windows, images, ios

OSX user here - sorry for the noob question. I am looking for a Windows software (as user friendly as possible) to list, navigate, etc. images tagged with a specific label in iOS (using Adobe Bridge or something similar).

The program should at least allow to browse among all available tags, and to sort images chronologically. What do you recommend I use?